# VBA: Else without If Error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to run the following code, but I keep getting the Else without If Error in the first sub. The code is supposed to run through a column, open webpages if there is a url in the cell, then save the page info as a text file. If there is no url, then it just saves the text within that file as a text file. I can't figure out how to change the syntax to get it to work.

```
Sub LoopOverB()

Dim myRow As Long

myRow = 10

While Worksheets("Input_Format_A").Cells(myRow, 2).value <> ""
    If InStr(1, Worksheets("Input_Format_A").Cells(myRow, 2).value, "http://", vbTextCompare) Then Call url_Test(Worksheets("Input_Format_A").Cells(myRow, 2).value, "C:\mallet\test\" & Worksheets("Input_Format_A").Cells(myRow, 1).value & ".txt")
        myRow = myRow + 1
    Else
        Open "C:\mallet\test\" & Worksheets("Input_Format_A").Cells(myRow, 1) & ".txt" For Append As #1
        Print #1, Worksheets("Input_Format_A").Cells(myRow, 2).value
        Close #1

        myRow = myRow + 1
    End If
Wend
End Sub


Sub url_Test(URL As String, Filename As String)

Dim FSO As Object
Dim ieApp As Object
Dim Txt As String
Dim TxtFile As Object

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set TxtFile = FSO.OpenTextFile(Filename, 2, True, -1)

Set ieApp = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ieApp.Visible = True
ieApp.Navigate URL

While ieApp.Busy Or ieApp.ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Wend

Txt = ieApp.Document.body.innerText
TxtFile.Write Txt
TxtFile.Close

ieApp.Quit

Set ieApp = Nothing
Set FSO = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you fix the carriage returns in your code? It's hard to tell if missing carriage returns are the problem or if that was caused by the way you pasted the code.

Comment: May I stronlgy recomment that you install and use Smart Indent (http://www.oaltd.co.uk/Indenter/) or do an effort to have proper indentation instead of that mess ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

On the line with the first `If`, you must go to a new line after `Then`, otherwise your `If` will be implicitely closed.

```
'Good (in this case)
If <condition> Then    
   DoSomething
   myRow = myRow + 1
Else
   DoSomething Different
End if


'NOT good 
If <condition> Then  DoSomething  
   'the if is now "closed" !!!
   myRow = myRow + 1
Else
   DoSomething Different
End if
```

Comment: smart indenter immediately highlighted the issue, because the `Else` did not line up with the `If`

Comment: +1 I needed to do my brothers homework on *QBASIC* and was cracking my head why it was not working. Its funny that this works though