# Error : Else without if

Tags: excel, vba

i'm trying to build an expense vs income excel and got this annoying error 
"else without if"
i went over different forums and other but can't get an answer - and it is driving me crazy

a bit explanation : i'm going over a table i have in sheet called "data" and if i find a cell which is not blank or without "0" i continue. the first 'for each' is for categories, the second is for sub categories - once i found a sub category i search for costs which we're made under that sub category. i look for costs in the month sheet which his name is in the string CSheet - when i found them i add them to the counter scSum.

> ```
> With Worksheets("Data")
>        For Each Mcell In Worksheets("Data").Range(.Cells(CatRow, stCatCol), .Cells(CatRow, enCatCol)).Cells '("C1:X1") expenses
>            scSum = 0
>           If Mcell.Value <> 0 Then
>                    If IsEmpty(Mcell.Value) Then Exit For
>                    Else
>                             For Each eScell In Worksheets("Data").Range(.Cells(CatRow + 1, Mcell.Column), .Cells(CatRow + noSubCat, Mcell.Column)).Cells 'run on sub category
>                            'eScell - expence category cell
>                                If IsEmpty(eScell.Value) Then Exit For
>                                Else ***'error!***
>                                subC = eScell.Value
>                                   With Worksheets(CSheet)
>                                       For Each eCcell In Worksheets(CSheet).Range(.Cells(ExpMonthStRow, ExpMonthSubCol), .Cells(MonthEndRow, ExpMonthSubCol)).Cells 'run in month and look for sub category expences
>                                          'eCcell - expence cost cell
>                                           If IsEmpty(eCcell.Value) Then Exit For
>                                           Else
>                                               If eCcell.Value = subC Then
>                                                   scSum = scSum + Worksheets(CSheet).Cells(eCcell.row, ExpMonthSubCostCol)
>                                               End If
>                                           End If
>                                       Next eCcell
>                                   End With
>                                End If
>                             Next eScell
>                     End If
>         'incomes
>         scSum = 0
>             End If
>         Next Mcell
> End With
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In VB after `THEN` you must go to a new line, otherwise the `IF` is implicitly closed.

You can compare with this other question on SO:

[VBA: Else without If Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15251829/vba-else-without-if-error)

Comment: +1 To clarify, you might want to change "implitely", which sounds like something rude, to "implicitly".

Answer (score 1):

The best method for finding an Offending `End If` is to `Indent` your code. :)

You can write `IF-Endif` in the following way.

**Multiple Statements**

```
If <Condition> Then 
    <Do Something>
Else
    <Do Something Else>
End If
```

or

```
If <Condition1> Then
    <Do Something>
ElseIf <Condition2> Then
    <Do Something Else>
Else
    <Do Something Else>
End If
```

**Single Statement**

```
If <Condition> Then 
    <Do Something>
End If
```

The above statement can also be written in one line

```
If <Condition> Then <Do Something>
```

In such a case, you do not need an `End If`.

You above code (after removing other code for demonstration) can be written as shown below. I removed the extra code to demonstrate what I mean. In the below code all the line starting with `*` is not required.

```
If Mcell.Value <> 0 Then
    If IsEmpty(Mcell.Value) Then Exit For
Else
    If IsEmpty(eScell.Value) Then Exit For
    *Else
    If IsEmpty(eCcell.Value) Then Exit For
    *Else
    If eCcell.Value = subC Then
        scSum = scSum + Worksheets(CSheet).Cells(eCcell.Row, ExpMonthSubCostCol)
    End If

    *End If
    *End If
    *End If
End If
```