# If In VBA Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, if-statement

Hi guys i'm having trouble with the next code:

```
Private Sub btnRegistrar_Click()


    If IsNull(txtNumeroActa) Then
        MsgBox "Ingresar Número de Acta"
        Me.txtNumeroActa.SetFocus
    End If
    ElseIf IsNull(txtNumeroActa) Then
        MsgBox "Ingresar NIT"
        Me.txtNumeroActa.SetFocus
    End If
    ElseIf IsNull(txtNumeroActa) And IsNull(txtNumeroActa) Then
        MsgBox "Ingresar Número de Acta y NIT"
        Me.txtNumeroActa.SetFocus
        Me.txtNumeroActa.SetFocus
    End If

End Sub
```

When I run it, there appears an error saying: Else without If any ideas ofa what I can check or change?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA: Else without If Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15251829/vba-else-without-if-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the End Ifs. Have a look at the syntax, maybe [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/Language/Concepts/Getting-Started/using-ifthenelse-statements) or [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/if_then.php)

```
If IsNull(txtNumeroActa) Then
    MsgBox "Ingresar Número de Acta"
    Me.txtNumeroActa.SetFocus
ElseIf IsNull(txtNumeroActa) Then
    MsgBox "Ingresar NIT"
    Me.txtNumeroActa.SetFocus
ElseIf IsNull(txtNumeroActa) And IsNull(txtNumeroActa) Then
    MsgBox "Ingresar Número de Acta y NIT"
    Me.txtNumeroActa.SetFocus
    Me.txtNumeroActa.SetFocus
End If
```