# Why do I keep getting the 'Else Without If' error on the following code?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am hoping someone can help me with the following code.  I keep getting the 'Else Without If' control error and I don't understand why?

```
If Sheets("Travel Expense Voucher").Range("D5") = 2 And Sheets("Travel Expense Voucher").Range("Meals") <> "" Then Sheets("Expense Code Processing").Range("C2") = "62495"
    ElseIf Sheets("Travel Expense Voucher").Range("D5") = 1 And Sheets("Travel Expense Voucher").Range("Meals") <> "" And cmbOVNRTN = ("Return") And cmbInOutState = ("In-State") Then Sheets("Expense Code Processing").Range("C2") = "62407"
    ElseIf Sheets("Travel Expense Voucher").Range("D5") = 1 And Sheets("Travel Expense Voucher").Range("Meals") <> "" And cmbOVNRTN = ("Overnight") And cmbInOutState = ("In-State") Then Sheets("Expense Code Processing").Range("C2") = "62410"
    ElseIf Sheets("Travel Expense Voucher").Range("D5") = 1 And Sheets("Travel Expense Voucher").Range("Meals") <> "" And cmbOVNRTN = ("Return") And cmbInOutState = ("Out-of-State") Then Sheets("Expense Code Processing").Range("C2") = "62430"
    ElseIf Sheets("Travel Expense Voucher").Range("D5") = 1 And Sheets("Travel Expense Voucher").Range("Meals") <> "" And cmbOVNRTN = ("Overnight") And cmbInOutState = ("Out-of-State") Then Sheets("Expense Code Processing").Range("C2") = "62417"
End If
```

Comment: Its because you have code after the Then so VBA see these lines as one line If statements. Move the code after the then to the next line down.

Comment: this question has been answered here:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15251829/vba-else-without-if-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15251829/vba-else-without-if-error)

Comment: Fixing it took that away, but now I'm getting a type mismatch error?  Is this because I am working with userform fields and spreadsheet fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indentation is needed for the `If` statement.

Also, you can use variables and a `With` statement to make it more clear.  I also added a `Boolean` to make the `ElseIf` a little shorter:

```
Sub t()
Dim ws As Worksheet, destWS As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Travel Expense Voucher")
Set destWS = Sheets("Expense Code Processing")
Dim oneMeal As Boolean
oneMeal = False
With ws
    If .Range("D5") = 1 And .Range("Meals") <> "" Then oneMeal = True
    If .Range("D5") = 2 And .Range("Meals") <> "" Then
        destWS.Range("C2") = "62495"
    ElseIf oneMeal And cmbOVNRTN = ("Return") And cmbInOutState = ("In-State") Then destWS.Range("C2") = "62407"
    ElseIf oneMeal And cmbOVNRTN = ("Overnight") And cmbInOutState = ("In-State") Then destWS.Range("C2") = "62410"
    ElseIf oneMeal And cmbOVNRTN = ("Return") And cmbInOutState = ("Out-of-State") Then destWS.Range("C2") = "62430"
    ElseIf oneMeal And cmbOVNRTN = ("Overnight") And cmbInOutState = ("Out-of-State") Then destWS.Range("C2") = "62417"
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: 'BruceWayne' - Duh...  I should have seen my first indentation.  Sorry about that.  It has been awhile since I have worked on this and any VBA coding so I think I may have lost a few VBA brain cells.  Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I am probably supposed to put this into another question but do I have to put this into a separate sub in order to use the variables?  I am still getting the mismatch error even with the indent before my 'if statement'.

Comment: @Kristen yeah likely a new question. You'll need also to include how this bit is being called and how you declares the variables.